# R How to replace value of a variable conditionally

Tags: r, if-statement

I am sure this question has been asked stacks of time but I couldn't find a solution.

I am trying to conditionally replace the value of a second variable based on the value of first variable. Here is the data.

```
 MAKE Continent
1  HOLDEN        US
2  HOLDEN        US
3    FORD        US
4    FORD        US

if(gsample$MAKE == "HOLDEN") gsample$Continent = "AUS"
```

Warning message:

```
In if (gsample$MAKE == "HOLDEN") gsample$Continent = "AUS" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: You can use `ifelse` which is vectorized, i.e. `with(gsample, ifelse(MAKE=='HOLDEN', 'AUS', Continent))` or just `gsample$Continent[gsample$MAKE=='HOLDEN'] <- 'AUS'` (Assuming that the column is `character` class).  Or a fast option using `data.table` is `library(data.table);setDT(gsample)[MAKE=='HOLDEN', Continent:= 'AUS']`

Comment: `gsample$Continent <- ifelse(gsample$MAKE == "HOLDEN", "AUS", gsample$Continent)`

Comment: Thankyou Avinash Raj & akrun.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the logical condition `MAKE=='HOLDEN'`, we use `ifelse` to return 'AUS' if that the condition is `TRUE` or else return the corresponding values of 'Continent'.

```
gsample$Continent <- with(gsample, ifelse(MAKE=='HOLDEN', 'AUS', Continent))
```

Or we use the logical index to subset the 'Continent' and replace that by assigning.

```
gsample$Continent[gsample$MAKE=='HOLDEN'] <- 'AUS'
```

Or we can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(gsample)`), based on the logical condition in `i`, we assign (`:=`) the Continent to 'AUS'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(gsample)[MAKE=='HOLDEN', Continent:= 'AUS']
```

NOTE: We assumed that the 'Continent' column is `character` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
gsample$Continent <- ifelse(gsample$MAKE == "HOLDEN", "AUS","US")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you want to change the value of a one column based on a value of a value in other column. Use following;

```
df$Continent[df$MAKE == 'HOLDEN'] <- 'AUS'
```

This will replicate all the values in the dataferame very quickly.

Comment: This is dependent on the `Continent` column being a character and not factor.